# Unable to access phpMyAdmin after a password is set to the database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

After I set password to MySQL, phpMyAdmin is denying access to the database and is showing the following error:

> MySQL said:
>
> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I have googled it and tried to mess with the config file, I tried everything, but couldn't come up with a solution. I even went through the previous questions of Stack Overflow, but the answers there also didn't change the situation.

Here is my `config.inc.php` file:

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']            = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']                 = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']             = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']      = true;

/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']             = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']     = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']         = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'root';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']            = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable']    = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation']         = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info']       = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']     = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']        = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']      = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history']          = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords']  = 'pma_designer_coords';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir']   = '';
$cfg['SaveDir']     = '';

$cfg['AllowAnywhereRecoding']       = true;
$cfg['DefaultCharset']              = 'utf-8';
$cfg['DefaultLang']                 = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation']  = 'utf8_general_ci';

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en';
$cfg['MySQLManualType'] = 'searchable';

?>
```

Comment: Given the error message, it would appear phpmyadmin's not sending the password over.

Comment: how r u connecting put some connection code

Comment: @G molvi I am using xampp control panel to access phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the code you should have for the phpmyadmin config.inc.php file:

```
   <?php

          $i = 0;
          $i++;
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
          $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

   ?>
```

If you are having issues w the host configuration, you should use:

```
         $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

If that doesn't work, here's another work-around that doesn't require any coding:

- open /scripts/signon.php page in your browser under PHPMyAdmin folder
- enter the the login details
- Then another login screen pops-up, enter the mysql details

Comment: tried the above method, no luck. I am ending up with the same error. I don't have this /scripts/signon.php file as i am using xampp. Please help

Comment: Thanks brian, Worked fo rme. Would be great if you can add why this would happen?

Answer (score 4):

1) Go to the directory C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin and open the file config.inc.php

2) Then find the line 21 and change it to (123456 is my mysql root password)

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123456';
```

3) Then find the line 34 and change it to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '123456';
```

4) Save the file. Then try to refresh the mysql page. This must work in most cases..

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Too..
Leave Your Password Field Blank

```
<?php
/*
* This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
* cookie
*/
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE     SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
* Servers configuration
*/
$i = 0;

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = 'en';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma_savedsearches';

/*
* End of servers configuration
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is, inside config.inc.php, change the auth_type to 'cookie'

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Or, you can also set auth_type to 'http'

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

With either method, next time you login to phpmyadmin, it should prompt you for a username and password.

Source = https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types