# WAMP phpMyAdmin won't open

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I just recently installed WampServer Version 2.5 on my Windows 7 64bit machine. 
When I attempt to open phpmyadmin I get this message in browser:

[image]

I checked in my `config.inc.php` file and everything seems alright. Here are contents:

```
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue??
Many thanks, also I should point out the WAMP icon is orange which makes me think that perhaps a particular service might not be running.

Comment: Check if the port 3306 is used by another service or process

Comment: Did you do all the grants for root?  See if this helps you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223235/mysql-root-access-from-all-hosts

Comment: I just installed WAMP and tried to run it. Other than that I havent tweaked anything in the core folder.

Comment: You may find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993894/unable-to-access-phpmyadmin-after-a-password-is-set-to-the-database?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Restart all service in wamp or do this

1. Open command prompt > mysql dir of wamp like this
   c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-version\bin\
   Then we create a new password
2. Enter command mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
3. Restart all services using wamp status icon

Hope this helps

Edit to add privileges
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY ' your current password ' WITH GRANT

Comment: I did as you suggested and got this message: `Access denier for user root@localhost (using password: NO)`

Comment: I just installed the most  uptodate version

Comment: Check if that user has all privileges

Answer (score 0):

You can watch to solve your problem 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgcW4h6ZAro&t=7m21s
p/s: this is Vietnamese video :)

in `config.inc.php` you edit folowing code:

```
* First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//uncomment this
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//comment this
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

then exit wampserver, reopen wampserver, open PHPMyadmin, you'll show login form :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change auth_type .Use http then browse.when browse then wants user id and pass 
give right user id and pass:

```
 /* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';**
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

if not set admin password for mysql then see 
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD

However, if you want to change (or update) a root password, then you need to use the following command:

$ mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass

For example, If the old password is abc, you can set the new password to 123456, enter:

$ mysqladmin -u root -p'abc' password '123456'